# How to use custom widgets in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, widget

I am working on a temperature control app for a wireless thermostat. I really wanted a slider that has two nodes instead of one. The slider would define a temperature range. The thermostat would keep the temperature inside that range.

I found a widget I can use located here: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/390

How do I import that widget into my project so I can use it? I have searched all over the internet looking for a guide or instructions, but cant find any. I think I may be searching for the incorrect terms. I'm new to Android development, I mostly do embedded software.